# Using Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports and want to know about some good tutorial about it for vs 2010 and also that if i make setup project after my GDI+ application is complete then do i have to install something special like some engine on other client machine like sql needs database engine to be installed.

my main task was to print invoice that could have some things from datagridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this might answer your question, but here's a bet.

Crystal Reports may be installed as a standalone which doesn't require any Visual Studio or the like components to be installed. You might have a user PC with only Crystal Reports installed. Crystal Reports supports multiple data sources such as an Excel file, an ODBC data source or a direct database engine connection.

As for Crystal Reports for Visual Studio, it only comes with greater edition of Visual Studio than the Standard.

If you don't actually have it already installed, here's a link to download it free directly from SAP.
[SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp)

The SAP Community Network which provides a Crystal Reports Support Forum as well.
[Forum: .NET - SAP Crystal Reports](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/forum.jspa?forumID=313)

eLearning.
[The SAP BusinessObject and Crystal Solutions eLearning Catalog](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/businessobjects-elearning)

Learning links:

1. [SAP Crystal Reports - Getting Started](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/crystalreports?rid=/webcontent/uuid/a06adfc3-b7a8-2d10-43be-82044f145fbe);
2. [SAP Crystal Reports Design](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/crystalreports) (This page shall enlight your use of Crystal Reports).

As for GDI+ and stuff, I just can't say, as I have never ever used it. I don't really understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Should you have any other questions in regards to Crystal Reports, feel free to ask, as I have much experience with the product itself.